# Give a fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-optimization, fixed-point-iteration

consider the following equation 
$$x=\sin{x}-ax+30$$
(a) Give a fixed point iteration scheme that will converge for all values of $a$
(b) How do you know that the scheme will work for all values of $a$?

Please help me as I have tried different $g(x)$ for $x=g(x)$ but none of them worked for all values of $a$.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. What is a fixed point iteration scheme? Also could you specify what you have tried? Even if it does not work completely, this would help answer the question.

Comment: Is $a $ positive.

Comment: @Couchy311. The standard fixed point iterative scheme $x=g(x)$.
I have used following functions but $|g'(x)|<1$ restrict the values of a.
$g(x)=\sin{x}-ax+30$,$g(x)=\frac{\sin{x}+30}{1+a}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You must write your equation as

$$x=\phi (x). $$
to be sure the schema works and iterations will converge to the root, you  should have

$$|\phi'(x)|\leq k <1$$.

If $a\geq 0$, you could take

$$x=\frac {\sin (x)+30}{1+a} $$

Comment: new to this forum, not know the perfect norms

Comment: [+1] Your solution is simpler than mine ! I built my solution on a Newton's scheme in order that the derivative is zero for the fixed point, and indeed, its convergence is very rapid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

$x_{n+1}=f_a(x_n) \ \ $ with $ \ \ f_a(x):=\dfrac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+30}{1+a-\cos(x)}.$

Indeed

- the fixed point equation $x=f_a(x)$, i.e., $x=\dfrac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+30}{1+a-\cos(x)}$ is equivalent to the given equation.
- As $f_a'(x)=\dfrac{ \sin(x) [a x+x- \sin{x} -30]}{(a-\cos{x} +1)^2}$ is equal to $0$ when $x$ is equal to the fixed point (because then the quantity between brackets is $0$!), we can say that $|f'(x)|<1$ for all $x$ in a certain neighborhood of this fixed point, thus the convergence is guaranteed. But we must have a function that is always defined. If $a=0$, the denominator becomes $1-cos(x)$, thus can be zero, which makes the function tends to $\infty$  (which is not at all desirable...), whereas, if $a>0$, this will never happen.

It is very instructive to see the curves of some functions $y=f_a(x)$ (look below): the fixed point is classicaly obtained as the abscissa of intersection of the curve with the line whose equation is $y=x$ : at this point, the curve has a zero derivative as shown upwards ; thus the curve is very flat in such a point.

[image]

Remark: I have built function $f_a$ by considering Newton's convergence scheme $x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ which, with the initial function, gives:

$$x_{n+1}=\underbrace{x_n-\dfrac{x_n+ax_n-\sin x_n -30}{1+a-\cos(x)}}_{f_a(x_n)}$$

Comment: I have corrected an error in the description of function $f.$

Comment: using the function $x=\dfrac{x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))+30}{1+a-\cos(x)}$
$$\Rightarrow ax+x-x\cos{x}=x\sin{x}-x\cos{x}+30$$
$$x=x\sin{x}-ax+30 $$
which is not same as the given equation

Comment: let me go through it @JeanMarie

Comment: Take into account my correction.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. @JeanMarie Please clear the confusion.
$$f'(x)=\frac{( \sin{x} ) (a x+x- \sin{x} -30)}{(a-\cos{x} +1)^2}$$
what will happen when $a=0$ and $x=(2n)\pi, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So there exists point which will lead the solution to blow up to $\infty$ then this function is not defined for all values of a.i.e. $a\neq 0$  
My Question is that can we use any other continuous function other than $x\cos{x}$ which will make denominator not equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, look at the proposal of @Salahamam_ Fatima which is simpler than mine.

Comment: would you provide some link in which your method is explained. it would be very great

Comment: I just indicated at the end of my answer the origin of the function using Newton's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)